# Displaying values in modal from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have list of stories with images , content and title in ng-repeat.
When I click on particular story , I need a bootstrap model to open and values to be displayed . I am doing it by calling a function `showStories()`; But I couldnt do it . I am getting empty value since its globally declared as

```
            $scope.selectedStoryPreview =  "";
            $scope.selectedStoryContent = "";
            $scope.selectedStoryTitle  = "";
```

Html :

```
<div class="image" ng-repeat="item in filteredStories track by $index">
    <img ng-src="{{item.images}}" style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="showStories(item)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#storyPreview">
    <button><span>{{item.title}}</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.showStories = function(item) {

            $scope.selectedStoryPreview =  item.images;
            $scope.selectedStoryContent = item.content;
            $scope.selectedStoryTitle  = item.title;

        }
```

Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="storyPreview" role="dialog"  data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" style="padding-top: 8em;">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="modal-header imagemodalhead">
        <h4>{{selectedStoryTitle}}</h4>
        <a class="edit" ng-click="openmanageprofile()"><img src="css/images/edit.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="background: #eee;">


        <div class="row">

            <img class="file-imageStory" ng-src="{{selectedStoryPreview}}" />

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-sm-12 storyPrv">
                <span class="styletheStory">{{selectedStoryContent}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer imagefooter">
            <button type="button" class="button share" ng-click="closePreview()" style="background-color: #7B7D7D; color: black;">close</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: why dont you just do ng-click="showStories(item)">

Comment: am getting empty value since its globally declared as ""? What is declared globally?

Comment: please check the updated code.

Comment: Remove that declarations and instead add $scope.model={}; inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$scope.model` is `undefined`. Set it as `$scope.model = {}` This way
  you can dynamically add properties to it at compile time.
- Moreover, you could use `data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#viewdetails"` as the action event to point to correct
  modal.
- Also, no need to pass individual properties as arguments in the
  method `showStories(item)`, you could send out complete object and
  obtain its properties.

DEMO:

Click on the image to open modal.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.filteredStories = [{
    id: 1,
    images: 'sample1.png',
    title: "sample1",
    content: "content here..."
  }, {
    id: 2,
    images: 'sample2.png',
    title: "sample2",
    content: "content here..."
  }, {
    id: 3,
    images: 'sample3.png',
    title: "sample3",
    content: "content here..."
  }, {
    id: 4,
    images: 'sample4.png',
    title: "sample4",
    content: "content here..."
  }]

  $scope.showStories = function(item) {
    $scope.selectedStoryPreview = item.images;
    $scope.selectedStoryContent = item.content;
    $scope.selectedStoryTitle = item.title;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="image" ng-repeat="item in filteredStories track by $index">
    <img ng-src="{{item.images}}" style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="showStories(item)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#storypreview">
    <button><span>{{item.title}}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="storypreview" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="modal-header imagemodalhead">
          <h4>{{selectedStoryTitle}}</h4>
          <a class="edit" ng-click="openmanageprofile()"><img src="css/images/edit.png">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="background: #eee;">
          <div class="row">
            <img class="file-imageStory" ng-src="{{selectedStoryPreview}}" />
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-sm-12 storyPrv">
              <span class="styletheStory">{{selectedStoryContent}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer imagefooter">
            <button type="button" class="button share" ng-click="closePreview()" style="background-color: #7B7D7D; color: black;" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi , I tried same method , still my model popup with no values.

Comment: Can you update your question to add what you have tried?

Comment: I updated the answer based on your new update. I think you are missing the  `<div class="modal fade" id="storypreview" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog">` at the start of your modal.

Comment: Thanks @sajal , its mistake with my model. It works perfect now. I used your code. Great help and guide from you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If `modal` controller is different. Then send the value using `resolve` method. If the controller is same. Then I think it should display the values.

And provide the `id` of modal here :

```
<div class="modal-content" id="storyPreview" style="text-align: center;">
```

Comment: its same controller. But values are not displaying

Comment: Intialize `$scope.model` in the starting of controller. Sometimes the scopes are not defined, that's why the issue occurs.
Because you defined the scope in function. They are not accessible outside.

Comment: Can you please reproduce your problem on plunker.